# query builder convert the result of query builder to model object

Tags: php, laravel-5

can i convert collection that returned from query builder to object model for example this

```
 $collection = DB::table('post')->get();
        (App\post)$collection->first;
```

if no tell me another way to get all post from data base and get all comment to post isolated`enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you the first post:

```
$posts = App\Post::first()
```

Comment: When i have collection has many posts can i convert this item  in collection to model posta object

Comment: @soso Why do you want to use the generic query builder if you have a model? You can simply use the query builder for this model then - it gives you the exact same options and will do the casting...